# Unable to log in and flashing command line message after restarting frozen Ubuntu 16.04.1 using REISUB

Tags: boot, 16.04, bootloader, boot-repair, reboot

I restarted a frozen Ubuntu 16.04.1 session using Alt + PrtSc + REISUB and now the graphical login manager does not show and I cannot log in.
The following message briefly displayed and then disappears in an ongoing cycle.

```
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 12976130 (uid=0, gid=0, mode0100600, size=334)
/dev/sda1: clean, 959550/14221312 files, 50959728/56878080 blocks
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Start NTP daemon.
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
         Starting User Manager for UID 115...
[  OK  ] Started Session c2 of user gdm.
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 115.
         Starting LSB: Start NTP daemon...
         Stopping User Manager for UID 115...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC.
[  OK  ] Stopped User Manager for UID 115.
```

I managed to log in using Ctrl + Alt + F1, however after a few seconds, the screen flashes black, and continues displaying the message above in the same manner. I can press Ctrl + Alt + F1 and the login is still active.

I've tried restarting it a few times using the power button with no success.

How can this be resolved? I still have access to recovery mode.

Comment: press ctrl-at-f7 and login in graphical session. the messeges shown are not error messages btw

Comment: Nothing happens when pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7. No response at all. The graphical login manager is not displayed at any time.

Comment: what display managers do you have? if you aren't sure, which tell me have you installed other DE?

Comment: Just noticed that Ctrl + Alt + F1 stays logged in, even after the screen flashes the message (I have to press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to get back to the logged in session). Upon running cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager the following is displayed: /usr/sbin/gdm3.

Comment: aha! It seems you installed `gnome-shell` on top of Ubuntu. I experienced this same problem with gdm3. please use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and if it shows you a list of several display managers, select one `lightdm` using arrow key and hit enter. Then reboot. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I am running the Gnome variant of Ubuntu. After executing `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop` the screen flashing stopped. I tried running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and selecting `lightdm` and upon reboot the login manager is displayed. After trying to login the screen freezes, then briefly turns off and returns back to the original login screen. I also tried `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`, `apt-get remove --purge gdm3 gnome gnome-shell` then `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get autoremove` and rebooted. After that I reinstalled `gdm3`, `gnome` and `gnome-shell` and rebooted again. The problems remain.

Comment: Just tried reinstalling gnome desktop and xorg and per the linked instructions and still no success: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics.

Comment: have you tried installing lightdm instead as the display manager? install it and select it as default

Comment: Still no still. May have to reinstall clean after all...

Answer (score 1):

Try holding Alt+Ctrl+F2
It seems to do that randomly sometimes.  It could be due to a late start of gdm, but I'm not certain as I don't know what each application does exactly.  I do know that my graphical interface disappeared as well and went to that same screen, but the interface was still on tty2, so I just switched back over to it as simply as the above method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by booting in safe mode, then checking how much free space I had at the shell prompt using `df -h`.

The amount available was ZERO.

Removed the docker images and everything turned back to normal