# Lubuntu Start Error

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, lubuntu, bootloader

I am not able to switch of my laptop after /dev/sda1:clean:xxxxx line, a new window is flashed.

```
[ OK ] Ctreated slice User Slice of gdm.
       Starting User Manager for UID 122...
[ OK ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[ OK ] started User Manager for UID 122.
       Starting Daemon fr power management...
```

few lines are more there.

I searched alot for the solution.
I am able to open terminal by alt+ctrl+f2.

Please help me.
My laptop is not on dual boot.
I only have lubuntu in my laptop.

I also have the usb stick if the only option, I have to reinstall lubuntu please tell.I can reinstall lubuntu on my laptop because I don't have Important content here.

Please suggest.

Comment: what are the rest of the lines?

Comment: "aha! It seems you installed gnome-shell on top of Ubuntu. I experienced this same problem with gdm3. please use sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 and if it shows you a list of several display managers, select one lightdm using arrow key and hit enter. Then reboot. Let me know if that helps"

This is the solution given by someone in other question wait trying this.

Comment: @ravery

sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 

worked

Comment: The mentioned “another question”: https://askubuntu.com/questions/810337/unable-to-log-in-and-flashing-command-line-message-after-restarting-frozen-ubunt

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trying and searching a lot, this solution 
Of reconfiguring gnome worked well.

I used

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

A display manager flashed and in that selected **lightdm**.

after this `reboot`  command and we are done.

Comment: Next time don't leave important facts out of your question such as that you installed gnome-shell!